# Test Source not available vs 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

When I run my test in VS none of the changes I make to the .cs file are reflected.

Why does VS run a different test then the .cs I edit?

Also when debugging the test, "No Source Available" is displayed:

```
Locating source for 'C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EventLogger\VeodinRecorderTest\RecorderEventTest.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {d0 6b 22 fe d9 3c da ac 8d 85 3c a1 e3 3c 48 2e}

Determining whether the checksum matches for the following locations:

1: C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EventLogger\VeodinRecorderTest\RecorderEventTest.cs Checksum: MD5 {35 70 54 97 ff f9 2a 1 98 7d 45 db 8e 9d 71 7f} Checksum doesn't match.

The file 'C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EventLogger\VeodinRecorderTest\RecorderEventTest.cs' exists.
Looking in script documents for 'C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EventLogger\VeodinRecorderTest\RecorderEventTest.cs'...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you confirmed in the Configuration Manager that your Test project is selected to build?

In the toolbar where it says "Debug" or "Release," use that drop down and choose "Configuration Manager." Now, ensure that the proper projects are checked in the Build column.